# plist simpleXML, trouble accessing array list

Tags: php, xml, plist

Lets say I have a plist simplexml document that looks like this:

```
<dict>
<key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
<array>
    <string>armv7</string>
</array>
<key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
<string>6.0</string>
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
<array>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
</array>
```

I can access a string like so:

```
$obj->dict->string[0]
```

This will return 6.0 for me. However if I want to access the first string in the second array:

```
$obj->dict->array[1]->string[0]
```

PHP throws an error and doesn't like my reference to array. What's the proper syntax here? Not a whole lot of examples on apple plist simplexml documents out there. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `array` is a [PHP keyword](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php), it's going to be a syntax error to attempt to use it in that context.  What you'll need to do instead is wrap it as a *quoted string* inside `{}`, effectively turning it into a dynamic property name.

```
// Using the {"string"} dynamic property syntax:
echo $obj->dict->{'array'}[1]->string[0]
// Prints UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait
```

This is ambiguously documented in PHP's [variable variables, and variable properties syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) reference.

You can use it, more commonly than avoiding keywords, to construct properties dynamically as strings. It is handy, but not that well known.

```
// More often used to build properties or method names as strings...
///...Not that you need to do this...
$v1 = "arr";
$v2 = "ay";
echo $obj->dict->{$v1 . $v2}[1]->string[0];
```